# Is there a script to make Stack Exchange sites use the full width of the browser?

Tags: support, script-request

All the Stack Exchange sites are designed to take up a width of 1000px or less. Can this be expanded to have the content always try to take up all available horizontal space?

Comment: ? Is this supposed to go to [meta.se]?

Comment: @YummyUnicornRainbowTails I do not request this change for everyone using the site. I search for a [style](https://userstyles.org/) or script to modify the width for my personal use, so I hoped stackapps would be the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script: [StackOverflow CodeBox Options](https://stackapps.com/questions/8013/stackoverflow-codebox-options)

[image: options-menu]